# The spiritual significance of the sand mandala in Tibetan Buddhism

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, mandala

I have heard of and seen sand mandalas in Tibetan Buddhism.

Here is a picture:

[image: Sand Mandala]

**I have two questions, which are related:**

1. I have heard that upon completion they are erased to represent transience. Is this what the erasure represents?
2. What other spiritual significance does the mandala have in Tibetan Buddhism. I seem to remember something relating to a spiritual journey being represented in the mandala yet I am unsure. I would like clarification on this.

Comment: "Mandala" is not always "sand mandala". First, it may be done using media other than sand. Second, "mandala" in its wider meaning stands for configuration or layout of components comprising a context. For example "While not being a public figure, his wife clearly occupied a key place in Chogyam Trungpa's mandala".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to The [Tibetan Monks of Drepung Gomang Monastery](http://www.gomang.org/mandala.html)

1. 

> When finished, to symbolize the impermanence of all that exists, the colored sands are swept up and poured into a nearby river or stream where the waters carry healing energies throughout the world.
>
> > In general, all mandalas have outer, inner, and secret meaning.  On the outer level they represent the world in its divine form; on the inner level, they represent a map by which the ordinary human mind is transformed into the enlightened mind; and on the secret level, they predict the primordially perfect balance of the subtle energies of the body and the clear light dimension of the mind.  The creation of a sand painting is said to affect purification and healing on these three levels.